# Converting row values into column name in pandas in a peculiar condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Pandas I have a dataframe like below

```
data= [['A','B',3],['A','C',4],['A','D',5],['B','A',4],['B','C',4],['C','D',1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns =['Col1','Col2','Value'])
df
```

| Col1 | Col2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 3 |
| A | C | 4 |
| A | D | 5 |
| B | C | 4 |
| C | D | 1 |
| B | A | 4 |

I want to convert it as below

| A:B | A:C | A:D | B:C | C:D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 4 | `5 | 4 | 1 |

Note: first column A:B value is 7 because there exists combination (A:B) = 4 +  (B:A) = 3.

Please suggest a quick method

Answer (score 3):

Use `sorted` with `join` for both columns and aggregate `sum`, last transpose:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(df[['Col1','Col2']]
         .agg(lambda x: ':'.join(sorted(x)), axis=1))
         .sum()
         .T
         .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df1)
       A:B  A:C  A:D  B:C  C:D
0      7    4    5    4    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df.groupby([':'.join(sorted(t)) for t in zip(df['Col1'], df['Col2'
           ])])['Value'].sum().to_frame().T
```

output:

```
       A:B  A:C  A:D  B:C  C:D
Value    7    4    5    4    1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sets` to make order irrelevant or `sorted` to make sure you have consistent ordering

```
result = df['Value'].\           
          groupby(df[['Col1','Col2']].\
          apply(set,axis=1).apply(':'.join)).sum()

print(result['B:A'])
print(result)
```

but that gets you a series ...

```
B:A    7
C:A    4
C:B    4
D:A    5
D:C    1
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

if you want it the other way you need to make 2 small changes

```
result = df[['Value']].\           
          groupby(df[['Col1','Col2']].\
          apply(set,axis=1).apply(':'.join)).sum().T
print(result)
print(result['B:A']['Value'])
```

**note** that set does not care about order so it might be `A:B` or `B:A`

if you need it actually sorted to always be `'A:B'`(you should have specified that as part of your requirements) you will need to use `sort` instead of `set` as shown below

```
result = df['Value'].\           
          groupby(df[['Col1','Col2']].\
          apply(sorted,axis=1).apply(':'.join)).sum()

print(result['A:B']) # always sorted...
print(result)
```

Comment: why 2 conservatives .apply ? why not 1 apply with lamda and combine what you want to do with the 2 apply ?